# Formula for finding the days which lies in between a particular period

Tags: excel

I need a quick help on a formula for finding out the dates(if it lies between) in particular time.

Example:

Employee A has start date and end date. He takes leave in between the start and end date It should say "yes", if not "No" and it should also calculate the days too

```
Employee Start_date  End_Date    Leave_Taken_Start_date  Leave_Taken_End_Date   Answer  Days
A        05/01/2014  06/15/2014  05/17/2014              05/21/2014.            Yes     4
```

Please help. The answer should be "Yes" 4 days.

Comment: You need to provide more information such as 1) What if the leave taken starts in the period but ends after? 2) What if it starts before, but ends during? etc.... AND will the leave always be between those 2 dates? Or can it simply be completely different date-ranges / blank? what would the inputs be like as a whole?

Comment: If it starts between the start date ends after the end date just say "Yes". It is not necessary that leave should be between start and end. The leaves may between the start or end date. It will be any date that the employee has taken leave.

Comment: Just as a heads' up - We usually want to see what you have tried first before helping, but I've dealt with this often enough that the solution was very quick for me to compute for you... I'll post it now....

Comment: I had no idea what formula has to used John. I thought Stack over flow would help me.

Comment: Again, I posted the solution this time, but the idea here is that you try SOMETHING and we help you along... We're all here because we enjoy helping and learning from each other, but we always want to see that someone has AT LEAST TRIED something before we jump in

Comment: @user3934399 Is the employee on leave on both the Leave_Taken_ Start and End dates?  If so, I'm sure he'd be happy to be charged for only four days instead of five; if not, then we need to know in order to tell which days in the period to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the data starting in Column A, your 2 calculations would then be in Columns F & G.

With the headers in the first row, so starting at cell F2, you could put in the following:

```
F2:  =IF(AND(D2<=C2,E2>=B2),"Yes","No")
G2:  =IF(F2="Yes",MIN(E2,C2)-MAX(D2,B2),"")
```

And, if you, as you said in your comment, don't want to show a value if the Leave_End > End_Date, then:

```
G2:  =IF(AND(F2="Yes",E2<=C2),E2-MAX(D2,B2),"")
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you have StartDate in Col B, End in Col C, Leave_Start in Col D and Leave_End in Col E? If so, this should work - Assuming that they are all dates - I copied your question and used it to test my formulas in my sheet....

Comment: John, F2 says the leave taken date as No. actually the leave dates which we have given lies between the start date and end date

Comment: I'm using your EXACT data and getting a "Yes" - The only thing I'm changing is that your cell `E2` has a `.` after the date, (`05/21/2014.`) so excel didn't register it as a date... I **assumed** that was a mistake in your inputting the question, though, and not in your live data... Do you have that in your sheet too??

Comment: Now I am able to get the solution for F2, I had space in B2 & C2. What about G2? Are you getting the answer as 4?

Comment: Yes I am... I don't know what you have there that's stopping it from working, but check your data....

Comment: While working with the formula shared, there came another doubt. If the Leave end date exceeds the end date then? How we will track it?

Comment: @user3934399, this was my original question... These are, unfortunately things for you to consider how you wish to track them... I'd suggest you give this project a bit more thought and try more things.... with relation to **your posted question**, the solution works, that's all I can offer.... If this solution worked for you, then mark it as solved, THEN I'd suggest you go back to the drawing board and re-think how you want things to work as whole.

Comment: Great. Sure I will do that. Hence Solved. Thanks John. Appreciate your prompt support

Comment: Hope you got it working finally!!! - As for how it works in this site, go ahead and select the check mark next to the solution to mark it as solved... That way other people can use this as a resource knowing that the solution did what it was supposed to do... Good luck!!!